# Custom PDO Class Errors

Tags: php, pdo

> **EDIT**: It turns out that I've been barking up the wrong tree so to
>   speak. I've edited the question to make it at least useful for others
>   who get the error.

For all those who get the following error when trying to execute a prepared PDO query:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]:
>   SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
>   on line 26

See my answer below.

Comment: Why do people seem to feel that OO DB drivers need wrapper classes? They already *are* classes. If you must change the way they work, *extend* them rather than wrapping them in something. Which line is line 26?

Comment: Also please don't ommit curly braces. It only hurts readability.

Comment: @PeeHaa It works either way. I never use leading `:`s in keys I pass to `execute()`.

Comment: @PeeHaa: thanks for the response, but it still does not work.

Comment: Have you verified the values of both `$query` *and* `$data` just before line #26?

Comment: Yes: `Array ( [id] => 1 )` and `SELECT * FROM cp_invoices WHERE invoiceid = :id LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you are passing more array values in `$query->execture($array)` than you have `:values` in the query. If you are getting a similar but differently worded error, it mean you have more `:values` in the query than you have in the array. For example:

```
$array = array(
  'username' => 'Bob',
  'id' => 42,
);

//...

$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`=:id";

//...

$data->execute($array);
```

This would give an error because, although you are passing "username", it is never used in the query. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't you supposed to be using the following syntax for your parameter array:

```
array(':id' => 1)
```

Note the colon that is omitted in your original post.

See the [PDO docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#example-998) for examples.